# Creating profiles in WAS 8559 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, websphere

I have installed WAS 8559 NDTrail on CentOS 7 OS - core install. 
[root@CentOS1 tools]# uname -a
Linux CentOS1 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@CentOS1 tools]# ./imcl listInstalledPackages
com.ibm.cic.agent_1.8.5000.20160506_1125
com.ibm.websphere.NDTRIAL.v85_8.5.5009.20160225_0435

Now i am trying to create deployment manager profile using the below

/opt/IBM/WebSphere85/bin/./manageprofiles.sh -response Dmgr01_profile.txt

create
profileName=Dmgr01
profilePath=/opt/IBM/WebSphere85/profiles/Dmgr01
templatePath=/opt/IBM/WebSphere85/profileTemplates/management
serverType=DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER
nodeName=CentOS1CellManager01
cellName=CentOS1Cell01
isDefault

The profile creation was partially successful with below message

Returning with return code: INSTCONFPARTIALSUCCESS

The initial errors that i could see in the log was below.

2016-07-10T09:19:56
    1468122596212
    306
    com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment
    INFO
    com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.osutils.ProcessEnvironment
    getEnvironmentVariableValue
    0
    Value of WS_CMT_EXTRINSICS could not be extracted from the process environment, returning null

Please suggest what needs to be done avoid these messages and install the profiles successfully on CentOS7

Comment: I don't think you've got the right snippet. Can you throw the logs in a pastebin/gist?

Comment: here is tthe log file - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3bad9636e2e5f225d813c28bee4fc6a7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me from your log that there is some config action to run "killall" which fails and likely causes your partial success.

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/killall
psmisc-22.20-9.el7.x86_64
```

Are you missing this package or maybe have a PATH that omits /usr/bin somehow.

Comment: thanks coverner.. yes my system was missing that package. installed the same [root@CentOS1 bin]# rpm -qa | grep psmisc
psmisc-22.20-9.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem after updating to WebSphere 8.5.5.11 and CentOS 7.

Our installation scripts failed already at the configuration of the Deployment Manager with the profileTemplate "dmgr". Changing the profileTemplate to "management" didnt work as well.

After checking the log output from the manageprofiles.sh script in

- /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/create_DMGR.log

one Exception was visible to us:

```
<record>
  <date>2017-11-15T14:49:16</date>
  <millis>1510753756354</millis>
  <sequence>3762</sequence>
  <logger>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.logging.LogUtils</class>
  <method>logException</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>The exception message is: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "killall" (in directory "/export/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/management/actions"): error=2, No such file or directory</message>
</record>
```

The problem is, that the "**killall**" command is not installed by default on CentOS 7 and can be easily installed via yum

```
yum install psmisc
```

After doing this the installation went fine.